# How can I bring my text to the front and leave the image on the background?

Tags: html, css, position, frontend, z-index

This is my first question after reading and solving my problems with stackoverflow's community.

I want to bring my title and subtitle to the front. I've tried with z-index but it still doesn't work. thank you for the help.

This is the code: https://codepen.io/gabrielacaesar/pen/gWyqJb?editors=1100

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  height: 65vh;
  background-image: url("images/alvoradaBetoBarataPR7maio2017.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: top;
}

.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(95%);
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.grayscale.blur {
  filter: blur(3px) grayscale(95%);
  z-index: 5;
}

.title h1,
.title h2 {
  z-index: 666;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 85px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title img {
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -666;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="title grayscale blur" alt="Foto: Beto Barata/Presidência da República - 7.maio.2017">
    <h1>alto escalão</h1>
    <h2>os poderosos indicados pelo Palácio do Planalto</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In that CodePen your text is in front. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmLeZp?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webkit blur applies to everything in the container, the only way around it is to put the image with the blur in an absolutely positioned container below the text. See this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmLeZp?editors=1100

PS: justify-content: top is not valid.

HTML

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="title grayscale blur" alt="Foto: Beto Barata/Presidência da República - 7.maio.2017">
    </div>
<div class="content">
        <h1>alto escalão</h1>
        <h2>os poderosos indicados pelo Palácio do Planalto</h2>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.title {
    height: 65vh;
  width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: top;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

.grayscale {
    filter: grayscale(95%);
}

.blur {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

.grayscale.blur {
    filter: blur(3px) grayscale(95%);
}

.content {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}
.content h1, .content h2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.content h1 {
    font-size: 85px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Signika', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.content h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Z-Index only applies tags in the same level.
Something like this won't work (Because text is inside the container):

```
<container>
    <text>
    </text>
</container>

container {
    z-index: -1;
}
text {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Well, something like this works:

```
<container>
</container>
<text>
</text>

container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Because both tags are in the same level.